# What is an efficient way to convert an adjacency matrix to a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

I'm wondering what is an efficient way to covert an adjacency matrix to a dictionary representing connections between one node and another?

Example matrix:

```
matrix = [
[0,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0]
]
```

Example output:

```
{0: [1], 1: [], 2: [1, 3], 3: [], 4: [3, 5], 5: [0]}
```

My code below actually generates the correct output; however, I believe it's very inefficient because I'm using two for loops. Is there any way I can optimize my code without using any libraries? Please let me know, and thank you!

```
def convertAdjMatrixtoDict(m):

    graph = {}
    for idx, row in enumerate(m):
        res = []
        for r in range(len(row)):
            if row[r] != 0:
                res.append(r)
            graph[idx] = res
    return graph
```

Comment: You only visit each adjacency once. That's about as fast as it's going to get. Libraries are not free performance. Just because you don't see the operations doesn't mean they are any more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more Pythonic solution which may be a little faster.

```
{i: [j for j, adjacent in enumerate(row) if adjacent] for i, row in enumerate(matrix)}
```

I doubt you'll get much faster in raw Python. I'll think about whether there are any solutions which leverage fast libraries such as `numpy`.

Update: I timed the two solutions using the following.

```
import numpy as np

# Make a big example
num_nodes = 1000
matrix = np.random.randint(0, 2, [num_nodes, num_nodes])

# Convert to raw Python
matrix = [[element for element in row] for row in matrix]
```

Your solution took 0.62 seconds, mine took 0.12 seconds. So in fact there is a good speed up of a factor of about 5.

Comment: @djennacs No problem. I'm not sure where the speedup comes from -- probably because it builds the objects all at once rather than appending items. I've tried a solution using `numpy.nonzero`, but simply to call this function and iterate over its result (without building any dictionary) takes longer than my solution already (0.15 seconds), so I don't think that approach will help.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a much better performance by usung `NumPy` to locate nonzero elements in each row:

```
import numpy as np
{i: np.nonzero(row)[0].tolist() for i,row in enumerate(matrix)}
```

Timings for a random 1000x1000 matrix:

1. original code: 310ms
2. @Denxiloe's code: 91ms
3. This code: 20ms